# What does the <%= domain %> mean in this YAML config file

Tags: yaml, prometheus

Was checking the config file below and confused what those symbols mean.

*xyz.yml*

```
job_name: xyz
metrics_path: "/some-metrics"
static_configs:
  - targets:
    - xyz.dev.<%= domain %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as YAML is concerned, this is just content. It is, however, [eRuby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERuby) syntax, which can mean that the YAML file is preprocessed with eRuby before being given to the YAML parser.